# Extending div element's height based on its absolute position descendant

Tags: css

I have this layout in my html page body

```
<div id="main">
...
<div id="menu">
</div>
...
</div>
<footer>
```

css for main:

```
#main {
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#cacaca;
background-size:cover;*/
position:relative;
display:block;
z-index:0
}
```

The div with id menu is a vertical navigation menu which can extend vertically. Its position is set to absolute in css.
Now I have this problem: if the menu extends, it may overlap with the footer below because the main's height is not extended accordingly. One solution is to set the height of main to be the biggest possible value after the menu is extended, but that is not optimal. My question is how can I make the main area's height grows according to its menu descendant with css so that the overlapping won't happen? Thanks.

Comment: you can achive this using jQuery

Comment: Using only css this is not possible, but with javascript it is very doable.

Comment: Thanks. Seems I have to use javascript in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comment there isn't anyway to do this with only css.

Using jquery this line will do it.

```
$('#main').height($('#menu').height());
```

You could do it on page load *or* if the size of the menu is changing put it in the code that changes the size of the menu *or* put it in a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var mainHeight = $('#main').height();
    var menuHeight = $('#menu').height();
    if(mainHeight < menuHeight) {
        $('#main').height($('#menu').height());
    }
},2);
```